# Cannot identify webelement on webpage where there is noscript iframe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, ui-automation

[html source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKQKl.png)
Having attached html source which include noscript iframe which is hidden and different about normal iframe directly under visible element such as div but this iframe is under noscript.
Tried to switch to this iframe using either src/id or other attributes do not work.
Without switching to this iframe also did not work, not sure what is wrong.
The problem is trying to identify the element such as button which is easily identified in devtools using xpath, but in the code using the same attribute (i.e. By.xpath("//button[@id='user-name-form-submit']")) will not work, similarly for every other visiable element on the webpage, xpath in devtools works but not in the code. Thus suspect it is the problem for iframe, any help will be appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrxjM.png)

The problem is trying to identify the element such as button which is easily identified in devtools using xpath, but in the code using the same attribute (i.e. By.xpath("//button[@id='user-name-form-submit']")) will not work, similarly for every other visiable element on the webpage, xpath in devtools works but not in the code. Thus suspect it is the problem for iframe, any help will be appreciated!
Using C# with visual studio

Tried to identify element using default content does not work
webDriverWait?.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//button[@id='user-name-form-submit']")));

Tried to identify element switching to iframe using src or other attribute does not work
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'GTM-MZXB4R4')]")));

Also tried to list all iframe on page and found 22 none of them shows the hidden iframe inside noscript

iframe Count : 22
iframe : iFrameSurveyReminder
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe :
iframe : iframe
iframe : xdiTag
iframe :